# XENSERVER - PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found

Tags: xen, xenserver

We use XenServer to host our VPS and when we tried rebooting the server we get the following error right away

```
PCI: Fatal: No config space access function found
```

We need to edit the grub file for the VM.

We have found the following which should work but we just keep getting the error `You must specify the correct partition number with -p`

```
xe-edit-bootloader -u 9bd6c821-138b-4f16-0bf9-efbaf3637c5b -p 1
```

Output

```
[root@ns337 ~]# xe-edit-bootloader -u 9bd6c821-138b-4f16-0bf9-efbaf3637c5b -p1
Creating dom0 VBD: f33a9d00-f5fb-ba33-a517-9e8e3a3d6484
Plugging VBD: 
add map 74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371c1 (252:13): 0 1024000 linear /dev/sm/backend/3e69e59a-9d18-407a-2a37-8f2fdb2ac319/74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371c 2048
add map 74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371c2 (252:14): 0 4193277952 linear /dev/sm/backend/3e69e59a-9d18-407a-2a37-8f2fdb2ac319/74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371c 1026048
Waiting for /dev/mapper/74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371cp1: .....Device /dev/mapper/74f174da-2d1e-4e9b-8837-93f8ab11371cp1 not found.
You must specify the correct partition number with -p
Unplugging VBD: . done
```

OS boot parameters are currently `graphical utf8` what can I change that to boot into rescue mode?